# Permission Denied trying to copy files from my Google Compute Engine Instance to my local drive

Tags: ssh, permissions, google-compute-engine, scp

I have an VM instance with Google Compute Engine and I am trying to copy a file from it to my local machine.  I have tried lots of things suggested by people in similar, though not exactly the same, situation, and nothing has worked.

The command I enter is:

```
$ gcloud compute scp <my name>@instance-1:<my patch> ~/Desktop
```

And every time I receive this error:

```
(gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource: - Insufficient Permission
```

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated as this is necessary for a school assignment and also incredibly frustrating

Edit for anyone else: I literally just didn't log in lol.  For me the solution was to simply use

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

Comment: Check for the File permissions of the file you are going to copy. You should have read permissions to copy file from one location to another. Also you should have read and execute permission on the directory which has your file.